# Neural Network Architecture for Time Series as Inputs and Outputs with Variable-Length Inputs

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I'm currently learning and working on implementing a time series prediction using different packages TensorFlow, Pytorch Neural Network. My goal is to feed a combination of time series data (GM Data) and various other related parameters (ST Data) into the neural network in order to predict the displacement response (DISP Data), which is also a time series (Displacement vs time) with same length of the feed GM Data.

> For example :
>
> - Input : 100+10 (GMdata+STdata) --- ndarray(110, 1)
> - Output: 100 (DISPdata) -------------- ndarray(100, 1)

Here is a simple illustration of the model I wanted [MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzrdt.png).

The code is first fed with randomly generated data just to ensure the reliability of the code before using real data.  where I made the output (DISP) just double X2 the input (GM)

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Generate synthetic data ------TODO Change with real data
np.random.seed(0)
num_samples = 1000              # Number of samples to feed the Neural Network
num_features = 1                # Number of columns in GM curve (Just acceleration)
gm_sequence_length = 100        # Maximum length of GM curve
st_sequence_length = 10         # The number of structural parameters

# Inputs data
structural_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (num_samples, st_sequence_length, num_features))
ground_motion_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (num_samples, gm_sequence_length, num_features))
# Combine structural_data and ground_motion_data (Generate an array of 110 length)
combined_data = np.concatenate((structural_data, ground_motion_data), axis=1)

# Output data just X2 the value of input GM 
displacement_data = ground_motion_data * 2 

# Data preprocessing
input_sequences = []
output_sequences = []

for i in range(num_samples):
    input_sequences.append(combined_data[i])
    output_sequences.append(displacement_data[i])

X = np.array(input_sequences)
Y = np.array(output_sequences)

# Splitting into train, validation, and test sets (60%, 20%, 20%)
split_ratio = [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
split_index_1 = int(split_ratio[0] * len(X))
split_index_2 = int((split_ratio[0] + split_ratio[1]) * len(X))
X_train, X_val, X_test = X[:split_index_1], X[split_index_1:split_index_2], X[split_index_2:]
Y_train, Y_val, Y_test = Y[:split_index_1], Y[split_index_1:split_index_2], Y[split_index_2:]

# Define and compile the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(gm_sequence_length+st_sequence_length, num_features), return_sequences=True),
    Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
epochs = 20
batch_size = 32
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

# Evaluate the model
mse = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("Test Mean Squared Error:", mse)

# Make predictions (Generate Random Data to predict the equivalent displacement should be Double)
new_acceleration_sequence = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (gm_sequence_length+st_sequence_length, num_features))

# Predict the displacement sequence (Here should feed it with ndarray:(110, 1) to predict ndarray:(100, 1))
predicted_displacement_sequence = model.predict(np.array([new_acceleration_sequence]))

print("New Acceleration Sequence:")
print(new_acceleration_sequence)
print("Predicted Displacement Sequence:")
print(predicted_displacement_sequence)
```

The code get me an error

```
  File "C:\Users\\\\12.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 110 and 100 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential/dense/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,110,1], [?,100,1].
```

I cound't figure out the problem. I'd appreciate any insights or recommendations you might have regarding the model. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to solve this problem, you have to install and update these items
And after solving these problems, you won't get any errors and the program will start easily for you

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg
pip install qrcode
pip install --upgrade
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
pip install tensorflow
```

After installing the program, the output of the program will be like this and according to the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVEbb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0yfO.png)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Have you made any modifications to the code? I am still encountering the same problem. Even after update. 
In colab also it didnt work

Comment: answer is up too code edit.

Comment: no code is ok just update items

Answer (score 0):

Please, yes, I will upload the source code here, and also try to install and update the tools that I announced, if there is a problem, let me know.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Generate synthetic data ------TODO Change with real data
np.random.seed(0)
num_samples = 1000              # Number of samples to feed the Neural Network
num_features = 1                # Number of columns in GM curve (Just acceleration)
gm_sequence_length = 100        # Maximum length of GM curve
st_sequence_length = 10         # The number of structural parameters

# Inputs data
structural_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (num_samples, st_sequence_length, num_features))
ground_motion_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (num_samples, gm_sequence_length, num_features))
# Combine structural_data and ground_motion_data (Generate an array of 110 length)
combined_data = np.concatenate((structural_data, ground_motion_data), axis=1)

# Output data
displacement_data = ground_motion_data * 2

# Data preprocessing
input_sequences = []
output_sequences = []

for i in range(num_samples):
    input_sequences.append(combined_data[i])
    output_sequences.append(displacement_data[i])

X = np.array(input_sequences)
Y = np.array(output_sequences)

# Splitting into train, validation, and test sets (60%, 20%, 20%)
split_ratio = [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
split_index_1 = int(split_ratio[0] * len(X))
split_index_2 = int((split_ratio[0] + split_ratio[1]) * len(X))
X_train, X_val, X_test = X[:split_index_1], X[split_index_1:split_index_2], X[split_index_2:]
Y_train, Y_val, Y_test = Y[:split_index_1], Y[split_index_1:split_index_2], Y[split_index_2:]

# Define and compile the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(gm_sequence_length+st_sequence_length, num_features)),
    Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
epochs = 20
batch_size = 32
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

# Evaluate the model
mse = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("Test Mean Squared Error:", mse)

# Make predictions (Generate Random Data to predict the equivalent displacement should be Double)
new_acceleration_sequence = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (gm_sequence_length+st_sequence_length, num_features))

# Predict the displacement sequence (Here should feed it with ndarray:(110, 1) to predict ndarray:(100, 1))
predicted_displacement_sequence = model.predict(np.array([new_acceleration_sequence]))

print("New Acceleration Sequence:")
print(new_acceleration_sequence)
print("Predicted Displacement Sequence:")
print(predicted_displacement_sequence)

gamma = list(zip(new_acceleration_sequence, predicted_displacement_sequence))
print(gamma)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).